# Visual studio is it possible to select line then find and replace text in selected area?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

Need to know many times I need to replace code in selected lines and I am doing one by one because I dont need to change it on whole file or project. Is it possible to find and replace in selected area ?

Example i have these 8 line code i need to replace `_monday` only on the last fourth (Mean which i have selected)

[image]

Comment: check the button **Find in Selection** in the Find dialog next to the **X**

Answer (score 4):

Yes, but it looks like you need to do it in a certain order, otherwise it will un-highlight your selection.

1. Open "Find" with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>.
2. Highlight whatever text you want to replace some text in.
3. Use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> or click the three lines icon in the Find control to toggle the "Find in Selection" option.
4. Replace the text as your normally would, and it should now only replace any text within the highlighted text.

Example for reference:

[image: selected text replace]

Comment: That should be the answer!